How to fix tensorflow "hanging"/buffering fitting error?
I have been struggling to get my TensorFlow code to run at all, since it randomly started buffering indefinitely. Decided to build a super simple LSTM to fix this error, here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import requests as req
import yfinance as yf
import seaborn as sns
import bottleneck
import pyarrow
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Input
import numpy as np

# Generate dummy data
x_train = np.random.random((100, 20, 1))
y_train = np.random.random((100, 1))

model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(20, 1)),
    LSTM(1),
    Dense(1, 'linear')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, verbose=1)


I have added logging statements into my code and the data processing elements work fine, the problem lies in the actual fitting of the model itself, whenever I run this cell it just returns:

2024-04-27 16:18:28.825928: I
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow
binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in
performance-critical operations. To enable the following instructions:
AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate
compiler flags.
Epoch 1/5

But the training never actually completes nor does it progress onto the next epoch. No errors are thrown, and no additional text/error messages are printed out to the console.
I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling tf and keras, as well as installing previous versions with no success. Additionally, my local machine has plenty of storage, so SSD/RAM is not the issue at play here. Genuinely no clue what to do here, no errors to go off of, hoping some ML expert on here has run into this problem before lol.

I have successfully executed the code in TensorFlow 2.17.1 .Please refer
gist with the code is attached for your reference.Let me know if you are still
facing the issue
